# Replacing the contents of an Item in MSBuild?

Tags: c#, .net, build, msbuild, msbuild-task

I have an Item list that I'd like to sort in a certain way before doing anything with it (for example before displaying its contents).  I've written a custom task to do so, and it works fine when used in a target as follows:

```
<Target Name="List">
  <SortProjects In="@(Projects)">
    <Output ItemName="SortedProjects" TaskParameter="Out"/>
  </SortProjects>
  <ListProjects In="@(SortedProjects)"/>
</Target>
```

So that's great, but what I'd really like to do is modify @(Projects) itself rather than make a new Item:

```
<Target Name="List">
  <SortProjects In="@(Projects)">
    <Output ItemName="Projects" TaskParameter="Out"/>
  </SortProjects>
  <ListProjects In="@(Projects)"/>
</Target>
```

That way I could split things up into multiple targets:

```
<Target Name="Sort">
  <SortProjects In="@(Projects)">
    <Output ItemName="Projects" TaskParameter="Out"/>
  </SortProjects>
</Target>

<Target Name="List">
  <ListProjects In="@(Projects)"/>
</Target>
```

And then I could make the "Sort" target an InitialTarget, so that it is automatically run before any of the many different targets like "List" that I intend to build, rather than needing to put a SortProjects task into every single target like "List".

Unfortunately, when I try to direct the Output to @(Projects), it does not overwrite the contents of @(Projects); instead, it appends to them.  So ListProjects lists the unsorted projects followed by the sorted projects.  I'm pretty confident that this is not due to some obvious algorithmic mistake in the SortProjects task.

Is there a way to replace the contents instead of appending to them? Or, more generally, some other way to accomplish what I'm trying to do here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to sort every time. Just use the DependsOnTargets property to specify that the Sort target gets called before a particular target. This way if you use it multiple times it gets called just once.

Answer (score 0):

Use Remove attribute of item (applicable inside a target only):

```
<Target Name="List">
  <SortProjects In="@(Projects)">
    <Output ItemName="SortedProjects" TaskParameter="Out"/>
  </SortProjects>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Projects Remove="@(Projects)"/>
    <Projects Include="@(SortedProjects)"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Note that each ItemGroup belongs to global scope even if defined inside a target.